# What does "#" do in scrapy selectors?

Tags: scrapy

I'm learning the examples on the [scrapy doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors).

Here is the full HTML code in question.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href='http://example.com/' />
  <title>Example website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='images'>
   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I completely understand this command selects the text nodes in all `<a>` elements.

```
response.css('a::text').getall()
```

The tutorial explains this command selects all descendant text nodes of **the current selector context**

```
response.css('#images *::text').getall()
```

I guess "*::text" might mean all the text nodes. What does "the current selector context" mean? What does "#" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is css selector equivalent to `id` and it looks like `scrapy` threats it the same.

```
<div id='images`>
```

Current selector context is the element you start your search from. Where you are at. In this case, you are at `<div>` with `id=images`.
`*::text` collects the text nodes of all of the child elements. All `<a>` tags with images in your case

Comment: Thank you. What does the space do between "#images" and "*::text"? Getting rid of it causes errors.

Comment: @JJJohn This is also part of `css selector`. This is how css knows you look for descendants of current selector context. Other example: `css('div#images a[href='image1.html']')`. It simply means "look for <a> element with `href` image1.html but reduce scope of search to div with `id` images"